# How can I create a bootable USB from an ISO image?

Tags: filesystem, ntfs

I'm trying to make a bootable USB drive from an `ISO` file. I have been trying with WinUSB.
In the WinUSB graphical interface my USB drive is not showing up, even though it auto mounts. So I'm trying to do it from the command line following these steps:

> To install a Windows ISO on NTFS partition and edit the Master Boot Record (MBR) of the device use the following commands:
>
> $ sudo winusb --install iso /path/ /partition/
>
> Example :
>
> $ sudo winusb --format Desktop/SETHO/Win7.iso /dev/sdd1

[WinUSB: Create A Bootable Windows USB In Linux](http://www.unixmen.com/winusb-create-bootable-windows-usb-linux/)

I don't understand what they want me to edit in `MBR`.
And what is the second command for `--format`. Isn't it enough to run `--install`

Do I need to have the ISO mounted in `/media/`. And how can I be sure it will be bootable?

Comment: In the GUI my USB is not targeted.

Answer (score 1):

If you've an ISO file of the Windows installation disc you can simply use `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/disc.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Or if you've a real disc:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/dev/sdb
```

Replace `/dev/cdrom` by the device path to your CD-ROM drive (if you've only one this is usually `/dev/cdrom`).

**You should replace `/dev/sdb` by your USB drive's device path (which seems to be `/dev/sdd` in your question).**

This will copy the ISO or disc bit for bit to your USB drive.

Comment: I was specific trying to understand the WinUSB commands to do it, since I don't want to `dd`.
I'm also wondering about mount. Do I need to mount the ISO and how do I assure that the USB will be bootable, for example doing `dd`.

Comment: You don't have to mount the ISO as `dd` (and I think `winusb` as well) will just read from the ISO file directly and write it to the USB drive (`winusb` writes the files to a partition). I don't know `winusb` but I think `--format` will format the USB drive so that it's bootable, and `--install` will copy all the files to the USB drive. It'll always be bootable using `dd` and it should also be so using `winusb`.

Comment: Note that while this is technically correct it may be illegal to do so in your country.

Comment: @ElderGeek : how would `dd` be illegal ? It's not, it's the content you copy bit per bit that could be illegal. Here it's an Ubuntu ISO, so it's not illegal...

Comment: Quote from answer "If you've an ISO file of the Windows installation disc" - Read the title of the question. thanks

Comment: @MrVaykadji Answer to your question above.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple idea

Download and install unetbootien 
Run unetbootien 
And then leave it all upto the software

Comment: Why would you install Wine for UNetbootin? There's a native version for Ubuntu, it's even in the repositories (`apt-get install unetbootin`).

Comment: Oh I didn't know that :-\

Comment: Now you do! :) The official PPA can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ppa) to always get the latest version using `apt-get`. You could update your question with this information if you like

Comment: Sir it's not my question, probably the person who asked it can edit it

Comment: I meant update your answer my bad.

Comment: I don't think it will work, unebootin does not list windows as a supported distro, I have it installed